# How to format address lines in Swift?

Tags: swift

There is a line in the code that does't transfer into the newer version of Swift. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong in the syntax.

```
let addressLines = placemark.@properties!["FormattedAddressLines"] as! NSArray
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting three errors: " Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' ", " Expected expression ", and " Expected member following '.' "

Comment: Show this code in some context. And explain what each variable is and its type.

Comment: `@properties` isn't valid Swift syntax, and hasn't ever been as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You should also avoid using `NSArray` in Swift. Use a proper Swift array. You should also avoid all of those crash operators (`!`) in your code.

Comment: @Shannon: please read this on how to ask a proper question on SO. The more info you provide, the better the chance for a useful answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is expressed through the CLPlacemark `postalAddress` property.

```
            let address = placemark.postalAddress
```

That line won't compile unless you also `import Contacts` at the top of your file.

Okay, so now you are in the Contacts world! What you have is a [CNPostalAddress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnpostaladdress). You can ask the CNPostalAddress for its `street`, `city`, `state`, and other properties; even better, you can use a [CNPostalAddressFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnpostaladdressformatter) to format the address nicely as a multi-line string (which looks like what you're actually after).

```
            let f = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
            print(f.string(from: address))
```